# Kivy: get no double tab from mouse

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to detect a double tab in a kivy app on laptop with Ubuntu, kivy v1.8.0, python 3.4.0
The following code causes an error: (AttributeError: 'MouseMotionEvent' object has no attribute 'is_double_tab')

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class MyWidget(Widget):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        print(touch.is_double_tab)

class Test_app(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test_app().run()
```

Superclass of MouseMotionEvent is MotionEvent. And this has a ".is_double_tab" attribute!
Is it possible to detect a double_tab from a mouse by something like "touch.is_double_tab"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word is tap, not tab, and so the property name is `is_double_tap`, not `is_double_tab`.